# Unable to include fs.js (node externs) in my code. I am using google closure compiler along with node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to use fs.js in my application.  I am trying to include this line in my application, but the google closure compiler throws an error:

```
var fs = require('fs');
PA057887MAC:project_test khuranar$ grunt build

Running "exec:closure_dependencies" (exec) task

Running "closure-compiler:build" (closure-compiler) task
>> grunt-google-closure-compiler: /src/main.js:7: ERROR - Failed to load module "fs"
>>  var fs = require('fs');
>>           ^
>> 
>> 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
Warning: Compilation error Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I know this is something related to the combination of closure compiler with nodejs.

FYI - If I use command line to check whether my application is reading the file or not, it does. 
I persoanlly think, there should be some changes done to the gruntfile, but I am not sure. It'll be great if someone could help.

I am very new to Google closure compiler.

Thanks,
Ritika

Comment: Show us your Gruntfile.  Also, consider using TypeScript.

Comment: 'closure-compiler': {
   build: {
    files: {
     'build/example-project.min.js': ['<%= closure_dependencies %>']
    },
    options: {
     create_source_map: 'build/example-project.min.js.map',
     source_map_location_mapping: '/src/|',
     source_map_format: "V3",
     externs: [
    //  compilerPackage.compiler.CONTRIB_PATH + '/nodejs/events.js',
    //  compilerPackage.compiler.CONTRIB_PATH + '/nodejs/stream.js',
      compilerPackage.compiler.CONTRIB_PATH + '/nodejs/fs.js'
     ]
    }
   },

Comment: Please edit your question.